# How to run multiple commands in a IF statement?

Tags: c#

So in my programming language I am making, I am adding if statements, so far it can tell if a variable equals another variable, and this is the code:

```
if (line.Contains("IF"))
{
    string n1 = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1).Split('=')[0];
    string n2 = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('=') + 1).Split(':')[0];

    string com = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':') + 1).Split(',')[0];

    string val = "";
    string val2 = "";

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in variables)
    {
        if (n1 == kvp.Key)
        {
            val = kvp.Value;
        }

        if (n2 == kvp.Key)
        {
            val2 = kvp.Value;
        }
    }

    if (val == val2)
    {
        if (com.Contains("PRINT"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PRINT");
        }
    }
}
```

The code snippet that says:

```
if (val == val2)
{
    if (com.Contains("PRINT"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PRINT");
    }
}
```

Should look if the area between `:` and `,` has PRINT and if it does then write out PRINT, here is an example of what it should look like:

```
$age=14;
PRINT:How old are you?
WRITE:>;
$newage=@;
IF age=newage:PRINT PRINT,
```

It sees if the ages are the same and if they are then PRINT, BTW @ means input, so it will get the user sets the new age, it does detect if the area between `:` and `,` contains PRINT, but it will only write out PRINT once, and I'm not sure what to do, I have tried using a list, and adding the items in-between them but I got the same output.

Comment: Oh, hand-made language parser. Are you sure? Maybe you'll consider tools like ANTLR: http://www.antlr.org/ ?

Comment: He means you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Use ANTLR. It is built for this.

Comment: But I've already come this far, I have more than just that code, its over 266 lines of code, and I don't want to have to rewrite it, but I will give it a look.

Comment: @EngineDev: it's great, that you're trying something yourself, but parsing some language using `string.Contains` or regular expressions is not an effective way.

Comment: It is your choice, but sooner or later you need a real parser. You can write one, or use the work of someone else.

Comment: Ahh, never mind, I should have kept reading

Answer (score 0):

I basically made another function that reads files, so instead of having to look for commands between `:` and `;`, you just type in the name of the file you want to run as your commands and it will run them:

```
if (val == val2)
{
    FileParse(f)
}
```

Its will do the same thing as the `TextParse(TextBox tb)`, but instead it looks for a file `FileParse(string filePath)`